# ExecutorService with invokeAll() and Future in java

Tags: java

Having the following code at hand:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Collection collection = new ArrayList();
    for (int n=1; n<100; n++)
        collection.add(new MyThread(n));

    try {
        List<Future<Boolean>> futures = executor.invokeAll(collection);

        for(Future<Boolean> future : futures){
            future.get();
            if (future.isDone()) {
                System.out.println("true");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("false");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If the above is correct?
And if all `future.isDone()` are true, then all of the threads have been done?
How can I make a flag, to be sure that all of them are done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if all are true, you can do something like this:

```
boolean works=true;
  for(Future<Boolean> future : futures){
        future.get();
        if (future.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("false");works=false;
        }
    }
if(works)System.out.println("yea it works")
```

Answer (score 20):

Meant as a comment on vainolo's reply but I don't have enough reputation points:

`isDone` is also redundant because `invokeAll` returns a list of futures for which `isDone` is true. The javadocs [mention this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. To clarify, invokeAll does not return until all tasks are completed, that is it is blocking. (There are overloads that are non blocking)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you add Runnable tasks to a Thread pool. Adding Threads to a thread pool isn't going to do what you think.

When future.get() returns for each task, all the tasks have completed.  The threads which ran the tasks will still be running.

If you want to stop all the thread once the tasks have completed you can use `executor.shutdown();` and `executor.awaitTermination`

---

The way I would write it is

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
    futures .add(executor.submit(new MyTask(n));

for(Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
    boolean result = future.get();
    // do something with the result.
}
```

If the result is not needed to you make the type `Future<Void>` or `Future<?>` or just `Future`

Comment: if it's not what i think, how can i be sure, that all threads done?

Comment: You add *tasks* to a thread pool, *not* threads as the thread pool already has threads of its own. If you add a Thread to a thread pool it won't even `start()` them because it is expecting Runnables.

Comment: So you can call it `MyTask` and you can wait until all your tasks are finished.

Comment: You can use invokeAll() but I prefer to create each one as I go.

Answer (score 2):

Using a boolean variable is the simplest way to understand that all threads are done.
Another way could be using a primitive, e.g. an integer. You could simply increment/decrement the counter to see if all threads are done.

And another way could be checking the return value of `awaitTermination()` invocation on your `ExecutorService` object.

```
  int counter = 0;

  for(Future<Boolean> future : futures)
  {
        future.get();            
        if (future.isDone())
            System.out.println("true");
        else
        {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("false");
        }
   }

   if(counter != 0)
       System.out.println("DONE!");

   // Another way of checking all threads are done.
   if(executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
       System.out.println("DONE!");
```

Comment: is that necessary to use .get and .isDone at the same time? If not, which is better for my question?

Comment: @fen1ksss get and isDone are different methods. so it is nonsense to ask "which is better for my question?". The way that you use these methods seem ok, i think.

Answer (score 1):

initialize a variable check with value =1       and update the value in the else .then check the value of check after the loop has executed

```
       if (future.isDone()) {
             System.out.println("true");
        }
        else
            {System.out.println("false");
             check=0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the method `future.get` returns then the computation done by the future is finished, so calling `isDone` is redundant. And yes, after all futures have finished all of the threads in the `ThreadPool` should be available.

Comment: so i can delete this part? if (future.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }

Comment: I think so. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) for `Future` states that `get` "Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.". So actually you also need to wrap `isDone` in its own exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Invokeall calling this method waits complete all take then CPU execution reaches to for loop to check for completion 
Or 
Do we need do .. While loop To check completion of tasks